# Why can't Animate function have nested parameters?

Tags: plotting, animation

Version: 12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Minimal example：

```
   Module[
 {c, C1, z},
 C1 = {c, 1};
 z[1] = {PointSize[.1], Point[C1]};
 Animate[Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 10}, 
   Prolog -> {PointSize[.1], Point[{c, 1}]}], {c, 1, 5}]
 (*Animate[Plot[Sin[x+c],{x,0,10},Prolog\[Rule]{z[1]}],{c,1,5}]*)
 ]
```

The above code works fine, but on the progress bar left it showed "c$12440" instead of "c", why and how to fix it?

More importantly, the following Code can't work:

```
    Module[
 {c, C1, z},
 C1 = {c, 1};
 z[1] = {PointSize[.1], Point[C1]};
 (*Animate[Plot[Sin[x+c],{x,0,10},Prolog\[Rule]{PointSize[.1],Point[{\
c,1}]}],{c,1,5}]*)
 Animate[Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 10}, Prolog -> {z[1]}], {c, 1, 5}]
 ]
```

Error Message is "Coordinate {\$CellContext`c\$18626, 1} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

Could someone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to scoping, the `c` control variable is not the same as the `c` external to the `Animate`. Pass the `c` as an explicit argument.

```
Module[{c, C1, z},
 C1[c_] = {c, 1};
 z[1][c_] = {PointSize[.1], Point[C1[c]]};
 Animate[Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 10},
   Prolog -> {z[1][c]},
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, 1.2}],
  {{c, 1, "c"}, 1, 5}]]
```

Answer (score 5):

One way maybe change the order of `Animate` and `Module`.

```
Animate[
 Module[{C1, z},
  C1 = {c, 1};
  z[1] = {PointSize[.1], Point[C1]};
  Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 10}, Prolog -> z[1]]], {c, 1, 5}]
```